PS: Redirecting error output of assignment statement to a variable
I am calling PnP-GetWeb like this:
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SecurableObject]$Web = Get-PnPWeb -Connection $pnpConnection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($null -eq $web) {
        throw "Could not get information for: $($pnpConnection.Url)"
    }

but when there is a 403 "Forbidden", it only outputs this to stdout. There is no exception thrown and I don't see a way to capture that error information unless I redirect stdout. It seems I need to capture its error output to a variable instead of to stdout so that I can format the error before logging it.
I this I can capture error output to a variable like this:
$output = Get-PnpWeb -Connection $pnpConnection 2>&1

but how do I both assign $web and $output?
UPDATE:
To clarify, this code is already inside a try/catch block. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier. However, no exception is ever thrown, even without SilentlyContinue.
Also, Get-PnPWeb does return $null when the stdout shows a 403.

you should be using -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue here, use proper error handling with try catches, i.e.: try { $web = Connect-Pnp.... } catch [System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException] { # handle http exception here } catch { # handle other exception here }

You are making a request and getting back a response with a status code of 403.  A good status is 200 OK.  $Web does is not equal to null.  So to capture all errors test for $web.status -ne 200.

Use  -ErrorVariable to assign the error in a variable, here is an example:
try {
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SecurableObject]$Web =
        Get-PnPWeb -Connection $pnpConnection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err
    if($null -eq $web) {
        throw "Could not get information for: $($pnpConnection.Url)"
    }
} catch {
    throw $_
}
if ($err) {
    throw $_
}


Perfect! Thank you.
